# How to make my app listed on the Appstore search?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I just uploaded an app into the appstore and it's already available on the Appstore. 
However, when I search the appstore using my app name (e.g "MyApp"), the listing doesn't show my app, only if I type "MyApp Insurance" only it will show.

How to make my app listed on the search?

Edit: I have put keywords such as ("MyAppName", finance, insurance).

Comment: You should put right keywords for your app, including your app's name. App Store search uses keywords for searching.

Comment: It takes time to index in search on app store, it will take around 6 hours to 1 day to come in search results if you search via app name.

Comment: @FahriAzimovI have put the app name as the keywords as well but it doesn't show.

Comment: @AmberK Thanks for the info, will wait 24 hours to and try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even with the keywords, it takes time for the app name to be indexed, and to show up based on your search terms.

If your `MyApp` name is not a common name and there aren't too many / popular apps containing that term, you'll start seeing the listing auto-populate in a few days (provided you are not the only one searching for that app).